# ArrayList on adding Hashmap gives NPE

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

```
    subMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    cursor = sdB.query(DataBase.TB, cols, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    limit = 1;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        limit +=1;
    }
    limit *= 2;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do{
        for(i=i+1; i<limit; i++){
            if(i%2!=0){
                subCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.C_CODE));
                subMap.put(TAG_SUB_CODE, subCode);
                Log.i("Alert", subCode);

                subjects.add(subMap);
                break;
            }
            else{
                subName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.SUB_TITLE));
                subMap.put(TAG_SUB_NAME, subName);
                if(subMap.containsKey(TAG_SUB_NAME))
                    Log.i("Alert", "Yes");
                if(subMap.containsValue(subName))
                    Log.i("Alert", "Again Yes");
                Log.i("Alert", TAG_SUB_NAME);
                Log.i("Alert", subName);
                subjects.add(subMap);
            }
        }
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
```

Gives me an NPE on `subjects.add(subMap)`in both if and else statement.
First else is executed then if. But program stops at first encounter with it in else block.
Can Anyone please help me.
I checked the existance of value and key in hashmap and it returned me true (`yes` and `again yes` ) in my log cat but still the subjects.add(subMap) returns an NPE.

Thank You

Comment: Where and how you initialize `subjects` ? Because if you get an NPE at this line: `subjects.add(subMap)` then your subjects == null

Comment: you don't show the declaration and definition of `subjects`. How is anyone supposed to know what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Ok...I got  it now..Thanks a lot...Thank you very much. Actually i forgot to add subjects = new Arraylist<Hashmap<String, String>>(); After adding it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your list `subjects`. For example like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subjects = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

If you don't do that then at this line:

```
subjects.add(subMap);
```

an NPE will be thrown.

Comment: Cool. As a further read about NPE, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/2399024

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `subjects` is null. Have you initialized it like this:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> subjects = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```